# problems installing thin on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems, thin

I'm trying to install Thin on Windows (ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]) but get an error message:

> C:>gem install thin Building native
>   extensions.  This could take a
>   while... ERROR:  Error installing
>   thin:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/rails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   checking for main() in c.lib... no
>   creating Makefile
>
> nmake
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance
>   Utility   Version 1.50 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corp 1988-94. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> ```
>     cl -nologo -I. -I. -IC:/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32
> ```
>
> -I. -MD -Zi -O2b2xg- -G6  -c -Tcparser.c 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NMAKE
>   : fatal error U1077:
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' : return
>   code '0x1' Stop.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.5
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.5/ext/thin_parser/gem_make.out

Google doesn't seem to help me here. Someone knows what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thin needs to compile a C extension used by it. While it seems you have `nmake`, seems that you don't have the complete Visual C++ 6.0 required to build it (the missing `cl` is the C compiler).

I would recommend you use the build of Ruby based on MinGW, called RubyInstaller, which is the successor of One-Click Installer.

Thin provides pre-compiled binaries for that Ruby version. Also, adding the Development Kit as documented in some [Tutorials](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/tutorials), you should be able to compile other gems that lack binaries for Windows.

You will find download details and more information in the RubyInstaller [website](http://rubyinstaller.org)

Also, if you have further questions, please read the [FAQ](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/faq) section of the wiki.

Hope that helps.